# What's the name of the color schema MacVim uses for QuickLook

Tags: vim, macvim, color-scheme

I really like the brownish QuickLook preview color schema which I think is provided by MacVim using [QLStephen](https://whomwah.github.io/qlstephen/). I cannot find where this color schema is defined. Can anybody identify this color schema? It looks like this: [image]

Comment: I don't think this is related to QLStephen which as far as I know is meant only to enable quicklook on extensionless files. Which other plugins do you have installed? (/Library/QuickLook and ~/Library/QuickLook)

Comment: Indeed QLStephen had nothing to do with it, MacVim neither. It was TextMate. This helped me find the responsible QuickLook generator: qlmanage -m plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out an old TextMate install was responsible for the QuickLook.generator. The theme name is Birds of Paradise.

The original version is here https://github.com/bergantine/Birds-of-Paradise-for-TextMate. There is a vim port is available here: https://github.com/ronny/birds-of-paradise.vim